# How to make a different margin on the pages itext 7?

Tags: java, pdf, itext, itext7

For example, on even pages, the indent is 100, on odd indentation - 150.
 page #1:

> doc.setleftMargin(100);

page #2:

> doc.setleftMargin(150);

page #3:

> doc.setleftMargin(150);

page #4:

> doc.setleftMargin(100);

This does not work:

```
for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
    if (n % 2==0)
        doc.setLeftMargin(100);
    else if(!(n%2==0))
        doc.setLeftMargin(150);

    doc.getPdfDocument().addNewPage();
    doc.add(pLiga);
    System.out.println(doc.getLeftMargin());
    System.out.println(doc.getPdfDocument().getNumberOfPages());

    n++;
    System.out.println(n);
}
```

**pLiga Added 5 times**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing low-level manipulations (`doc.getPdfDocument().addNewPage()`) with high-level ones (e.g. adding elements to `Document`). If you are using high-level API, you should try to stick with it as much as possible. To go to a new page you can use `doc.add(new AreaBreak());`. Also be sure to set margins before actually adding any content to a new page.

Rewriting your code into something like following works as expected - margins are alternating from page to page:

```
int n = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    if (n % 2 == 0) {
        doc.setLeftMargin(100);
    } else {
        doc.setLeftMargin(200);
    }

    // Make sure to set margins before adding elements to new page
    if (i > 0) {
        doc.add(new AreaBreak());
    }
    doc.add(new Paragraph("Hello"));

    n++;
}
```